# Sklearn's models take too much time with few data in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, data-science, bigdata

I've been working with sklearn's models (SVM, Logistic Regression, MLP,...) and until yesterday I hadn't any problems but I don't know why, currently when I try to fit a model, this takes a exaggerated amount of time.

For example with 551 samples with 6 features, trying to fit a Support Vectorial Machine with polynomial kernel and varying the parameters:

- C = 1.00 Degree = 1.00 Coef = 0.000 Gamma = 0.25 
  15.124 seconds.
- C = 1.00 Degree = 1.00 Coef = 0.000 Gamma = 0.75 
  22.937 seconds.
- C = 1.00 Degree = 1.00 Coef = 3.000 Gamma = 0.25 
  11.703 seconds
- C = 1.00 Degree = 1.00 Coef = 3.000 Gamma = 0.75 
  18.81 seconds
- C = 1.00 Degree = 2.00 Coef = 0.000 Gamma = 0.25 
  316.115 seconds
- C = 1.00 Degree = 2.00 Coef = 0.000 Gamma = 0.75 
  74.530 seconds
- C = 1.00 Degree = 2.00 Coef = 3.000 Gamma = 0.25 
  270.514 seconds
- C = 1.00 Degree = 2.00 Coef = 3.000 Gamma = 0.75 
  357.194 seconds

  ```
  from sklearn import svm

  for C in C_values:
      for degree in degree_values:
          for coef in coef_values:
              for gamma in gamma_values:
                  print('C = {0:.2f} Degree = {1:.2f} Coef = {2:.3f} Gamma = {3:.2f} '.format(C,degree,coef,gamma))
                  clf = svm.SVC(C = C, degree = degree, gamma = gamma, coef0 = coef, kernel = 'poly', decision_function_shape = decision_function_shape )
                  time_i = time()
                  clf.fit(X_train, Y_train)
                  time_f = time()
                  print('str(time_f - time_i) '+'seconds')
  ```

I don't change nothing from yesterday to today and I think that 5 minutes to fit a model with 550 samples and 6 features is exaggerated.

> What can be producing this increase of time?

Thanks

**EDIT**:

I've been trying with random_state parameter different times and the result is similar:

- C = 1.00 Degree = 1.00 Coef = 0.000 Gamma = 0.25......     7.359 scnds
- C = 1.00 Degree = 1.00 Coef = 0.000 Gamma = 0.75......      26.156 scnds
- C = 1.00 Degree = 1.00 Coef = 3.000 Gamma = 0.25......      8.781 scnds
- C = 1.00 Degree = 1.00 Coef = 3.000 Gamma = 0.75......     16.437 scnds
- C = 1.00 Degree = 2.00 Coef = 0.000 Gamma = 0.25 .....     259.248 scnds
- C = 1.00 Degree = 2.00 Coef = 0.000 Gamma = 0.75......     219.170 scnds
- C = 1.00 Degree = 2.00 Coef = 3.000 Gamma = 0.25......    302.201 scnds
- C = 1.00 Degree = 2.00 Coef = 3.000 Gamma = 0.75......     345.163 scnds

Comment: It may be caused by luck with the random parameters. You could run your performance tests with `random_state` set, to get comparable results: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html

Comment: But could luck produces an increment of 4 minutes?

Comment: I would say: yes :)

Comment: I've been trying ith the parameter random_state and I got similar results

Comment: This is not unusual in my opinion. Read up a bit on SVMs theory and you will observe that there is a strong dependence between learning-time and parameters (which is a classic caveat of grid-searches / random-searches). The slowest instances are probably generating many many support-vectors. You can verify this within sklearn by reading out the final result or switching on verbose-mode. (Also, but it's not that important here: the SMO algorithm is powered by many heuristics and these might have some variance)